Typescrip Error: error TS2769: This type parameter might need an `extends T[]` constraint
I have written a small filter function as follows:
const xcFilter = <T>(items: T[], filterFn: (item: T) => boolean): T[] =>
    items.reduce((a, v) => filterFn(v) ? [...a, v] : a, [])

The function is called as follows to filter a list of even numbers:
xcFilter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,], (v) => v % 2 === 0)

What am I missing? I am getting the following error:
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T, initialValue: T): T', gave the following error.
    Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T[]'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: never[], currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => never[], initialValue: never[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I also tried defining the filterFn outside rather than defining inline. Note that in either case, the error remains the same.

Fixed it. We need to cast the second parameter to as T[]
const xcFilter = <T>(items: T[], filterFn: (item: T) => boolean): T[] =>
    items.reduce((a, v) => filterFn(v) ? [...a, v] : a, [] as T[])



xcFilter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,], (v) => v % 2 === 0)


To adhere to best practices and to avoid using escape-hatches like type assertions (var as Type), it's recommended to explicitly type the accumulator in the reduce function as shown:
also it appears you are missing the generic type parameter  that precedes the function parameters which is also required for this to work
const xcFilter = <T>(items: T[], filterFn: (item: T) => boolean): T[] =>
  items.reduce((a: T[], v) => (filterFn(v) ? [...a, v] : a), []);

// The function is called as follows to filter a list of even numbers
xcFilter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], (v) => v % 2 === 0);

